# How could Draco be using his mother's wand, if she lost her wand the same day as him?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

In the movie version of Deathly Hallows, part 1, Dobby takes the wand of Draco's mother shortly after Harry takes Draco's wand.  Then in Deathly Hallows, part 2, Draco says he is using his mother's wand.  How did Cissy get her wand back in order to lend it to her son?  Dobby disapparated pretty much immediately after taking it.  Did Cissy own 2 wands?  No other wizards or witches (that I know of) have 2 wands of their own, so this seems unlikely.

Comment: Pretty much covered here- [Whose wand did Bellatrix use at the Battle of Hogwarts?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/171969/whose-wand-did-bellatrix-use-at-the-battle-of-hogwarts)

Comment: This explains some possible ways Bellatrix could have acquired a new wand...   I don't really see them as possibilities for how Draco's mother still had her own wand in order to lend it to Draco.  Draco specifically refers to it as his mother's wand - if it had been just recently acquired as a replacement for the one Draco had lost (even if his mother acquired it for him), he would not have referred to it as his mother's.  Am I off base here?  I think it must be, as Darth Locke stated, that Dobby left Narcissa's wand behind when disapparating from Malfoy Manor.

Answer (score 5):

According to a Harry Potter "Q & A" Page,

> Dobby disarmed her **but left the wand behind, as it was not in his
>   possession when he died.** If it was, Harry would have taken it, but
>   Harry only had three wands -- all of which were examined by Ollivander
>   -- but they belonged to Draco, Bellatrix Lestrange, and Peter Pettigrew.
>   http://harrypotter.answers.wikia.com/wiki/Why_does_Draco_Malfoy_get_his_mothers_wand_when_Dobby_disarmed_her_in_deathly_Hallows_Part_1

Also confirmed as a *possible expaination here:

> In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2, Draco Malfoy uses his
>   mother's wand during the Battle of Hogwarts, despite being taken away
>   by Dobby in Deathly Hallows: Part 1. **It is possible that Dobby dropped
>   it while teleporting**.
>   http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Narcissa_Malfoy%27s_wand